# IOS toggle StackView inside UITableViewCell when click on accessories button

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm developing an IOS app with tableview with customer data. My purpose is to display a list of user (title). When user click on accessory button (for example Detail Disclosure). More detail about user will be show up. When user click button accessory button again, detail will collapse to only title. Anyone know how to achieve this? I'm thinking of group all detail into a `StackView` and toggle `addarrangesubview`, `removearrangesubview` inside the method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Here is my cell design

[image]

And my tableview design

[image]

Comment: Sounds reasonable to me. Have you tried it? What is your exact problem? I think you can also just set the `hidden` property of the arranged subviews instead of adding or removing them completely.

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to put these code to manage the stackview (inside cell or in tableview?)

Comment: You could create a custom cell class that has methods such as `expand` and `collapse`. These could set the `hidden` property of the detail stack view.  The expand and collapse methods would then be called in `accessoryButtonTapped` for the appropriate cell.

Comment: Thanks, Can help for an example? how do we call the method inside the accessoryButtonTapped?